# NodeJS RegExp is different with regular express on finding digit

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I don't know why there are different between `re` and `/^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/g`.

Did I use wrong expression?

```
$ node -v
v6.15.0

$ node
> list =[ 'Text.json',
   'Text1.json',
   'Text2.json',
   'Text3.json',
   'Text4.json' ]
> re = new RegExp(/^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/g)

> list.filter(f => re.test(f))
[ 'Text.json', 'Text2.json', 'Text4.json' ]

> list.filter(f => /^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/g.test(f))
[ 'Text.json',
  'Text1.json',
  'Text2.json',
  'Text3.json',
  'Text4.json' ]

> String(/^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/g) === String(re)
true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/g` flag makes the same RegExp remember the end position of the last successful match and search from this position on even in the different string next time. If you use RegExp literal, regular expression is recreated each time and this behavior has no impact.

See note and examples [in this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test()_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Such a weird behavior.

Just remove the global flag and you are done.

```js
var list =[ 'Text.json',
   'Text1.json',
   'Text2.json',
   'Text3.json',
   'Text4.json' ]
var re = new RegExp(/^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/)

var filter1 = list.filter(f => re.test(f))
console.log('filter1', filter1)

var filter2 = list.filter(f => /^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/g.test(f))
console.log('filter2', filter2)

var comp = String(/^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/) === String(re)
console.log('comp', comp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slashes arround regex when using constructor:

<strike>`re = new RegExp(/^Text(\d+)?[.]json$/g)`</strike>
becomes:

```
 re = new RegExp('^Text(\d+)?[.]json$', 'g')
```